# How to throw an error when VBA Function takes longer than length of time to compute

Tags: vba, excel

I have a Function in my VBA code which downloads a file from an FTP which I call like so

```
success = fnDownloadFile(hostName, UserName, Password, _
        remoteFileStr, _
        desktopPath & "downloaded.csv")
```

Sometimes due to connection issues etc. this function hangs and does not respond. I would like to display an error message if this function takes more than 5 seconds not to set success = True and cancel execution of the whole sub.

I have tried messing around with the following just before the ftp function call but i couldn't get it to work:

```
Application.OnTime Now + TimeValue("00:00:05"), "checkIfSuccessIsFalseAndStop"
```

The code of the function is as follows:

```
Function fnDownloadFile(ByVal strHostName As String, _
    ByVal strUserName As String, _
    ByVal strPassWord As String, _
    ByVal strRemoteFileName As String, _
    ByVal strLocalFileName As String) As Boolean

    '// Set a reference to: Microsoft Internet Transfer Control
    '// This is the Msinet.ocx
    Debug.Print "Value for file passed as:" & strRemoteFileName

    Dim FTP As Inet    'As InetCtlsObjects.Inet

    Set FTP = New Inet 'InetCtlsObjects.Inet

    On Error GoTo Errh
    With FTP
        .URL = strHostName
        .Protocol = 2
        .UserName = strUserName
        .Password = strPassWord
        .Execute , "Get " + strRemoteFileName + " " + strLocalFileName
        Do While .StillExecuting
            DoEvents
        Loop
        'fnDownloadFile = .ResponseInfo
    End With
Xit:
    Set FTP = Nothing
    Exit Function

    fnDownloadFile = True
        Debug.Print "Download completed"
Errh:
    'fnDownloadFile = "Error:-" & Err.Description
    fnDownloadFile = False
    Resume Xit
End Function
```

Answer (score 2):

Just set the `.RequestTimeout` [property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa239748(v=vs.60).aspx):

```
With FTP
    .URL = strHostName
    .Protocol = 2
    .UserName = strUserName
    .Password = strPassWord
    .RequestTimeout 5       '<------
    .Execute , "Get " + strRemoteFileName + " " + strLocalFileName
```

Answer (score 1):

You should control this in your `.StillExecuting` loop

This should work I think. It mostly depends on what your `inet` class is: *custom* or *MSINET.OCX reference*. If it's custom you should have declared the `cancel` method.

```
Dim dtStart As Date
dtStart = Now
.Execute , "Get " + strRemoteFileName + " " + strLocalFileName
Do While .StillExecuting

    If DateDiff("s", Now, dtStart) > 5 Then
        ' Cancel after5 seconds
        .Cancel
        .Execute , "CLOSE" ' Close the connection
        MsgBox "Download cancelled after 5 seconds"
    End If

    DoEvents
Loop
```

Comment: the class is MSINET.OCX